# How to output a static row in SQL based on conditions

Tags: sql

I need to figure out how to output a row statically based on a condition that it is not in the database.

**Example Database:**

```
+ -------+-------+
| STATUS | SUM   |
+ -------+-------+
| P      | 1,000 |
| E      | 5,000 |
+ -------+-------+
```

**Desired Output**

```
+ -------+-------+
| STATUS | SUM   |
+ -------+-------+
| P      | 1,000 |
| E      | 5,000 |
| N      |     0 |
+ -------+-------+
```

Basically- In the event that "N" is not within the database, I need to output a row with N status that has a sum of 0. The reason I need to do this is for formatting reasons later. This is regarding file processing data, and while some months may have files in all three statuses, P, E and N, other months may only have P and E. I need a consistent output no matter the month.

Comment: Are you using MySQL, Excel or Teradata?

Comment: Most people here want data as formatted text, not images (or links to images.)

Comment: With database you mean *table*? So you have a table in a relational database (MySQL or Teradata presumably) that has two columns, `status` and `sum`? If so, you should rename the `sum` column, as `sum` is a reserved word in SQL. And you are talking of months, so there is a date or some month column in the table, too? Then show it. And then, you want a query to retrieve one month or several months? And please replace the image links with a text representation of the table and result.

Comment: You probably got another table with those 3 stati (if not, create it). Then it's a simple Left Join.

Comment: @courthale . . . I removed the incompatible database tags.  Please tag only with the database you are really using.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the two columns are "Status" and "Sum";

```
SELECT [Status], [SUM]
FROM YOURTABLE
UNION
SELECT 'N' AS [Status], 0 AS [SUM]
```

Comment: The OP has mentioned MySQL, Excel and Teradata. We don't know which of these products the request is actually for. Your query doesn't work for any of these, if I'm not mistaken. Is this T-SQL?

Comment: Yes this is TSQL

Comment: That's useless, you need to know in advance that there's no row with Status `N`.

Answer (score 0):

I would strongly suggest avoiding hardcoding the static rows within your SQL query, but instead create a separate table containing your 'default' values for each status, e.g.:

```
+ -------+-------+
| STATUS | SUM   |
+ -------+-------+
| P      |     0 |
| E      |     0 |
| N      |     0 |
+ -------+-------+
```

Then, you can construct a query with a `LEFT JOIN` to always include all records from this status table, e.g.: assuming the defaults table is called `MyDefaults` and your data table is called `MyTable`:

```sql
SELECT 
    MyDefaults.STATUS,
    COALESCE(MyTable.SUM, MyDefaults.SUM) AS [SUM]
FROM 
    MyDefaults LEFT JOIN MyTable ON MyDefaults.STATUS = MyTable.STATUS
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you want the `SUM` over this table's column, let's say its name is `COLUMN_NAME` and the table's name is `TABLE_NAME`. 
**If** this is the case then you must sum over the table plus a row containing the values `'N'` and `'0'` for the 2 columns. 
This makes sure that `'N'` will be there at the final result and even if it already existed it will not harm the final sum because of `0`:

```
SELECT STATUS, SUM(COLUMN_NAME) 
FROM (SELECT STATUS, COLUMN_NAME FROM TABLE_NAME UNION SELECT 'N', 0) 
GROUP BY STATUS
```